# Who decides this type of things in LIVE cricket matches?

Tags: cricket, media

One day I am watching ODI LIVE cricket in TV, they suddenly showed old bowling clip about some player and sometimes they will show net practice clips also in middle of LIVE ODI match. Who will decide to play this interrupting clips: commentators or ICC staff?

Commentators also talks about this type of clips immediately when they showed up on screen.

Answer (score 2):

Neither - the broadcaster does.

The commentators watch the broadcast themselves so that they are accurately describing what the audience will see, and can explain why something has happened when the camera or microphones didn't pick up all of it.